# Xamarin Controls piling on top of each other

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Im new to Xamarin, i'm seeing tutorials like the ones here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/hello-android/hello-android-quickstart?tabs=vswin

and the axml designer is supposed to "snap" controls to the border of the other controls you have listed, but mine isn't working this way. It's just piling them all on top of each other. Any clue how to remedy this? I've searched for a while but it seems like no one else is having this issue.

For example, they're all just being placed at the top left corner of the pane and even when placed 'correctly' at the bottom of another control, they're just snapping up to the top left corner.

Edit: Sharing XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
tools:gridSpec="1|8|#0093eeff|K:#ee8700ff:16,l:72,l:16,r|S:#83ee00ff:16,0,l:16,56,l:16,0,r">
<TextView
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/editText1" />
<TextView
    android:text="Text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/PhoneNumberText"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />
<Button
    android:text="Translate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/PhoneNumberText"
    android:id="@+id/TranslateButton"
    android:layout_above="@id/PhoneNumberText" />
<EditText
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/PhoneNumberText"
    android:id="@+id/PhoneNumberText"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="0.0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp"
    android:text="1-855-xamarin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Share your `xml` code

Comment: @Yupi shared xml.

Comment: Interestingly, I was just having this problem and was switching between Chrome and looking at this and back to the instructions on the website and Visual Studio.  I was reading this and went back to VS and suddenly they were no longer stacking.  They all were using layout_below and it just started working.  Some sort of bug in Xamarin or VS I'd guess.

Comment: I had this problem and closed activity_main.axml and reopened it and they were then in their correct positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Xamarin Controls piling on top of each other

Your `.axml` has several errors.

In your `textView2`:

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/editText1" />
//I didn't find where you define the id -- editText1
```

And please note: **Circular dependencies cannot exist in `RelativeLayout`**

> What is the layout you want to achieve?

Something like the image you post in the above link?

[image]

If so, you could modify your layout file to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text="Enter a Phoneword:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/PhoneNumberText"
        android:text="1-855-XAMARIN" />
    <Button
        android:text="Translate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/TranslateButton" />
    <TextView
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/TranslatedPhoneWord" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So, i've been going over this and i'm now wondering why this is working with "LinearLayout" but not "RelativeLayout". The MsDoc has relative so im a bit confuse on why it isnt working the way it seems it should be for this tutorial.

Comment: @York can you please explain a little bit why the MS uses RelativeLayout in their docs and it seems to work, but why it doesn't work in this case?

Comment: @antikbd, for this [Phoneword sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/hello-android/hello-android-quickstart?tabs=vswin&pivots=windows#related-links), MS use [LinearLayout](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/Phoneword/Phoneword/Resources/layout/Main.axml), not  `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: @York But [this screenshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/hello-android/hello-android-quickstart-images/vs/07-add-properties-w158.png#lightbox) shows them using `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: @antikbd, you could use `RelativeLayout` for this layout file. But to avoid the issue that Controls piling on top of each other, please use `android:layout_below="@id/textView"` as the picture you posted, for more detailed information, please refer to the [official document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved reading the notes in the tutorial:

> Newer releases of Visual Studio contain a slightly different app
>   template.
>
> ```
> Instead of activity_main.axml, the layout is in content_main.axml.
> The default layout will be a RelativeLayout. For the rest of the steps on this page to work you should change the <RelativeLayout> tag
> ```
>
> to  and add another attribute
>   android:orientation="vertical" to the LinearLayout opening tag.

Making those changes fixed my problem